# Problem with NamedPipeServerStream / NamedPipeClientStream

Tags: c#, .net-5, named-pipes

Trying to implement named-pipe functionality using basic examples from MSDN:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream?view=net-5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream?view=net-5.0

1. Creating a simple test server basically with four lines of code:

   `using (NamedPipeServerStream npss = new(pipeName))`

   `{`

   ```
    `MessageBox.Show("[1] npss.IsConnected: " + npss.IsConnected); // false, as expected`

    `npss.WaitForConnection(); // returns too early`

    `MessageBox.Show("[2] npss.IsConnected: " + npss.IsConnected); // true, as expected to be after .WaitForConnection() call, but actually not connected. more about it later here...`
   ```

   `}`
2. Creating a simple test client with the following code:

   `using (NamedPipeClientStream npcs = new(pipeName))`

   `{`

   ```
    `MessageBox.Show("[1] npcs.IsConnected: " + npcs.IsConnected); // false, as expected`

    `npcs.Connect(); // never returns, doesn't throw anything`

    `MessageBox.Show("[2] npcs.IsConnected: " + npcs.IsConnected); // not reachable code`
   ```

   `}`

The problem is that client cannot connect to the server at all (`npcs.Connect()` waits infinitely). But somehow server reacts (`npss.WaitForConnection()` returns) on client instantiation (`NamedPipeClientStream npcs = new(pipeName)` line), telling me that the client has connected (which is false). Now I have a server with `.IsConnected` property set to True, but the client never returns from `.Connect()` method (and it's `.IsConnected` state is false, I receive exceptions if I skip `.Connect()` before doing anything with pipe).

What am I doing wrong? Pipe name is the same, PC is the same, user is the same (just clicking the same app twice, it checks whether the pipe already exists or not, if not, creates a server, otherwise connects as client to it).

I'm running on .NET5. By the way, also tried to open a server + WinObjEx64 to try to access pipe manually. The tool finds it, but it shows an error 'Cannot open pipe because: All pipe instances are busy' when I try to open it. I've also tried to set maximum server instances count (-1), but no effect as well.

**UPDATE:** server creation like this (with waiting for connection -> disconnect -> waiting for connection again) seems to work. is it a normal way of connecting? I doubt it... would be nice if somebody describes what is happening here.

```
`using (NamedPipeServerStream npss = new(pipeName))`

`{`

    `MessageBox.Show("[1] npss.IsConnected: " + npss.IsConnected); // false, as expected`

    `npss.WaitForConnection(); // returns too early (on client instantiation)`
    'npss.Disconnect(); // disconnects to free the pipe'
    `npss.WaitForConnection(); // this time it returns after client.Connect(), which is a desired behaviour`

    `MessageBox.Show("[2] npss.IsConnected: " + npss.IsConnected); // true, as expected. now we are truly linked with a client, communication works`

`}`
```

Comment: Temporarily disable any installed security software and try again.

Comment: already tried to disable Windows Defender (nothing more is installed), no difference.

Comment: tried same code on my server machine (WinServer2012R1) - same behaviour. is it _actually_ a normal behaviour or is it a bug in .NET5?